# How to typecast Spark DataFrame columns? Using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have created a DataFrame in the following way:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("train.csv", header=True)
```

The schema for my DataFrame is as follows:

```
root
 |-- PassengerId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Survived: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Pclass: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sex: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SibSp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Parch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Ticket: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Fare: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cabin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Embarked: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I change the data types of each column of my DataFrame?

I know that I can specify the schema option in the call to csv(), but I want to change the data types after at a later stage.

Some of the columns have missing values. How do Spark DataFrames deal with missing values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the datatype you can for example do a `cast`. For example, consider the `iris` dataset where `SepalLengthCm` is a column of type `int`. If you want to cast that int to a string, you can do the following:

```
df.withColumn('SepalLengthCm',df['SepalLengthCm'].cast('string'))
```

Of course, you can do the opposite from a `string` to an `int`, in your case. You can alternatively access to a column with a different syntax:

```
df.withColumn('SepalLengthCm',df.SepalLengthCm.cast('string'))
```

Or, importing `from pyspark.sql.functions import col` you could do (without dealing directly with the `df`):

```
df.withColumn('SepalLengthCm',col('SepalLengthCm').cast('string'))
```

You can deal with null values using `df.na.drop(how='any', thresh=None, subset=None)` (or `df.dropna()`). This is the [doc page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) where you can check the meaning of the parameters.

> Returns a new DataFrame omitting rows with null values. DataFrame.dropna() and DataFrameNaFunctions.drop() are aliases of each other.
>   Parameters:
>
> - how – ‘any’ or ‘all’. If ‘any’, drop a row if it contains any nulls. If ‘all’, drop a row only if all its values are null.
> - thresh – int, default None If specified, drop rows that have less than thresh non-null values. This overwrites the how parameter.
> - subset – optional list of column names to consider.

You can also choose to assign a specific value if you meet null values. This time you should use `df.na.fill(value, subset=None)` (or `df.fillna()`). Here is the [doc page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna).

> Replace null values, alias for na.fill(). DataFrame.fillna() and DataFrameNaFunctions.fill() are aliases of each other.
>   Parameters:
>
> - value – int, long, float, string, or dict. Value to replace null values with. If the value is a dict, then subset is ignored and value must be a mapping from column name (string) to replacement value. The replacement value must be an int, long, float, boolean, or string.
> - subset – optional list of column names to consider. Columns specified in subset that do not have matching data type are ignored. For example, if value is a string, and subset contains a non-string column, then the non-string column is simply ignored.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. I still don't understand why it is so hard to find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this-

```
df1 = df.select(df.column1.cast("float"), df.column2.cast("integer"))
```